# Problems with list view after updating to java 8

Tags: java, listview, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

After updating to Java 8, i got problems displaying content of list view

```
  public class TestController extends AnchorPane implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        private ListView<String> listView;

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        }

        public void setApp() {
            setContent();
        }

        /**
         * Set content in list
         */
        private void setContent() {
            ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            items.add("1");
            items.add("2");


            listView.setItems(items);

        }
    }
```

With Java 7 this gives me a list with values. After update to java 8, it gives me a empty frame.

Thanks James_D, here is the code you asked for

```
public void goToTest() {
            try {
                TestController test = (TestController) replaceSceneContent("/fxml/test.fxml");
                test.setApp();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error loading: " + ex + " - " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

     private Initializable replaceSceneContent(String fxml) throws Exception {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            InputStream in = MainApp.class.getResourceAsStream(fxml);
            loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource(fxml));
            AnchorPane page;
            try {
                page = (AnchorPane) loader.load(in);
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }

            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.sizeToScene();
            stage.setResizable(resizable);
            return (Initializable) loader.getController();
        }
```

Comment: Yes, the setApp is called form a different class that loads the fxml

Comment: If I remove listView.setItems(items); i also get a empty frame. Maybe problem with FXMLLoader and initialise listView... 

When I do a System.out.println("listView.getitems is: " + listView.getItems().size()); it shows that it got contents, but it don't show in the GUI, only a empty frame

Comment: I did remove listView = new ListView<>(items); but same result - empty frame

Comment: Looks right... can you show some of the FXML (root element and declaration of the list view)?

Answer (score 1):

```
listView = new ListView<>(items);
```

will not work; it will create a new `ListView` and populate it, whereas what you want to do is populate the `ListView` you created in your FXML.

```
listView.setItems(items);
```

is the correct code.

(I assume you really have `public class TestController implements Initializable`, not `public class test implements Initializable`.)

So the following should work:

```
private void setContent() {
    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    items.add("1");
    items.add("2");

    listView.setItems(items);

}
```

Your `FXMLLoader` code is a little unusual in that you set a location (URL) but then use the `load(InputStream)` method to load. I'd be surprised if this fixed it, but the usual way would be:

```
    private Initializable replaceSceneContent(String fxml) throws Exception {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            // not needed:
            // InputStream in = MainApp.class.getResourceAsStream(fxml);

            // Not really needed, this is the default:
            loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource(fxml));
            AnchorPane page;

            // instead of this:
//            try {
//                page = (AnchorPane) loader.load(in);
//            } finally {
//                in.close();
//            }

            // just this (since you have set the location):
            page = loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.sizeToScene();
            stage.setResizable(resizable);
            return (Initializable) loader.getController();
        }
```

(Random guess: did you accidentally make `listView` static in the Controller?)